# Smart contract to Lock/Hold Solana tokens for a short period

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, solana-program-library

I have a solana program that will transfer some amount. After agreeing to the amount to transfer, the transaction will take place a little later. Few hours to few days. Is there a way my solana smart contract can put a hold/lock kind of enforcement to make sure the funds are available when the transaction takes place ?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for an escrow smart contract.

One example that is really well explained is this one https://github.com/paul-schaaf/solana-escrow

Comment: In escrow concept, will the user still see the tokens in his/her wallet. Or will they be moved and be within the solana account owned by the program managed by us.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few existing solutions that will do this for you, including the Bonfida token-vesting program and the Streamflow timelock program.

You can find more information about these programs at https://spl.solana.com/token#token-vesting

The idea is to move the tokens to an account owned by the timelock / vesting program, and then these funds are unblocked after a certain amount of time.

Comment: My case is the lock period is hours to maximum couple days. And we don't have receipient addresses by the lock time. Only before/around unblock time we have exact receipient addresses. Will that use case suited this?